# __init__.so (instead of __init__.py) masks subpackages

Tags: python, module, python-3.x, package, cython

I am writing some code in cython, and I have some ["Packages “within” modules"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047750/packages-within-modules). — This is actually a follow up to my question there, and the structure should be the same. The problem is that this is cython, so I'm dealing with `.so`'s not `.py`'s.

Having `__init__.so` works to the extent that,

```
import mystuff
```

will work, but it seems to mask all the subpackages below. That is,

```
import mystuff.test.test1
```

will not. I get an `ImportError: No module named ...` error.

How can I work around this? Is there something I need to add to the `.pyx` before compiling it to `.c`? Or perhaps I can rename `__init__.so` to something else, and somehow pull it into the `__init__.py` (Note, an `__init__.py` still needs to exist alongside the `.so` to show it's a package)? Or something else.

---

**Update: `__path__` attribute not defined for `.so` packages ...**

Ok, I had a thought that maybe I could get around this by manipulating the [`__path__`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories) attribute of the package. Interestingly enough, this is defined for `.py` packages, but causes an error with the `.so`'s. It's not a solution, but I wonder if it is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have your Cython code be in a different file than `__init__.py`, and import it into a normal python `__init__.py`  See my answer to your previous question.

Comment: I had thought of putting it in a seperate file and importing that from `__init__.py` but was worried about polluting my package with two modules that could be imported to do the same thing. I thought about putting a `.` in the name of the "real" module to stop it being imported, but of course this would stop it being imported from `__init__.py` too! I then got so bogged down in looking for complex solutions it didn't cross my mind to just underscore it. Perhaps a simple solution is best. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most simple solution to given problem would be to rename your `__init__.so` module into something like `_native.so`. Afterwards you can create `__init__.py` which would contain following line:

```
from _native import *
```

And it should work as you describe.